# From matrix to eps or png

Tags: export, eps-format, png-format

My output is a matrix. I want to save this matrix as a picture whose format is eps or png. How can I convert it?
Thank you.

Comment: Try using `ArrayPlot` or `MatixPlot` to visualize it (you will need to consider your choice or color map), then use `Export` to export the image to either eps or png, your choice!

Comment: via GUI, right click the bar at the far right of the expression and choose `Save Selection As`

Comment: thank you for your responce. These explanations are enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use `Export`

```
m = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {8, 10}];
Export["mat.png", MatrixForm[m]]
```

[image]

If you want to make it good looking, you can use `Style`. Following the suggestions of Verbeia and Edmund, you can do either

```
m2 = Map[Style[ToString[#], 16, Bold, FontFamily -> Times, Blue] &, m, {2}]//MatrixForm
Export["mat.png", MatrixForm[m2]]
```

[image]

or

```
m2 = Style[MatrixForm@m, 16, Bold, FontFamily -> Times, Blue]
Export["mat.png", MatrixForm[m2]]
```

[image]

Notice that in first case (Verbia) the style is attributed only on the text part, whereas in second case (Edmund) the style is attributed over the whole form.

Comment: `Map` takes a third argument to specify the level. `Map[yourfunction, yourmatrix, {2}]` will work. This is the fifth in the list of "Basic examples" in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).

Comment: You can also just style it all without map. `Style[MatrixForm@m, 16, Bold, FontFamily -> Times, Blue]`

Comment: Thanks @Verbeia. I was missing the `{}` for the argument before.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot` to visualize it (you will need to consider your choice or color map), then use Export to export the image to either eps or png, your choice! (Quantum_Oli)

Via GUI, right click the bar at the far right of the expression and choose Save Selection As (george2079)

Or use `Rasterize` to rasterize your expression, and `Export` to export it.